# VSTS extension - Getting work items for a specific team

Tags: javascript, tfs, azure-devops, wiql, azure-devops-extensions

I'm working on an extension for VSTS that requires me to get work items separated by team.

REST API contains [queryByWiql](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1#method_queryByWiql), which takes in a [WIQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/wiql-syntax) and an optional project and team. In the example below, I include a project and team in the call, but the results contain all open work items from all teams in all projects instead of only the work items assigned to the project/team provided.

```
function testing() {
  VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient", "TFS/Core/RestClient"],
  function(VSS_Service, TFS_Wit_WebApi, TFS_Core_WebApi) {

    //This gets the correct project information
    var witClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
    var projectId = VSS.getWebContext().project.id;
    var coreClient = TFS_Core_WebApi.getClient();
    var allteams = [];

    var query = {
      query: "SELECT [System.Id] "
            + "FROM WorkItem WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature' "
            + "AND [System.State] NOT IN ('Closed','Completed','Removed','Done')"
    };

    //This gets all of the teams in the project
    coreClient.getTeams(projectId).then(function(teams) {

      allteams = teams;

    }).then(function() {

      //This should get the open work items for a specific team in a specific project
      //Instead, 'result' contains all open work items from all projects
      witClient.queryByWiql(query, allteams[0].projectName, allteams[0].id).then(function(result) {

        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
        console.log(result);

      });
    });
  });
}
```

In the example above `result` should only contain the open work items for one team (`allteams[0].name`) in one project (`allteams[0].projectName`). Instead, `result` contains all work items.

Is there a different way to filter results by team?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. What's the version of vss-web-extension-sdk? Try to clear browser's cache and try again.

Comment: How can I check the vss-web-extension-sdk version? I used npm to install it within the last month, so I had assumed it was the latest.

Comment: There is package.json in vss-web-extension-sdk folder (node_modules\vss-web-extension-sdk), open it and check the version key. On the other hand, you can share a simple sample on the OneDrive.

Comment: I'm using version 5.127.1

Comment: It looks like the issue is actually caused by looping over a promise. I've edited the question to reflect this issue.

Comment: Since the results are the same, why you need to loop it? What's the scenario the result will be different.

Comment: I want to get the work items for a specific team. I've found a way to avoid looping over teams, but I'm still running into the original issue: queryByWiql is returning **all work items** instead of only work items from a specific project/team. I've edited the post to reflect this. Can you filter results by project/team using queryByWiql?

Comment: Based on the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#run-a-query), there isn't the team filter. How about filter it through area?

Comment: I have another copy that's filtering through area, but I had assumed that you could filter by team since queryByWiql takes both project and team. Filtering by area assumes that the area path is correctly set for all work items. Is this the only solution?

Comment: As far as I know the project parameter is used for `[System.TeamProject] = @project` condition, if there isn't such condition, the result will include other project's work items. Do not find the same thing for area.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll search by area.